# Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Problems and Directories are opened by EasyTag

Tags: upgrade, directory, 20.04

SInce I've upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS I'm not able to drag n drop or copy to the desktop directly.
In Addition, directories on the Desktop are opened by the programm EasyTag by default?!?!
Can someone help me please??

Answer (score 0):

Hey I too had the same problem when i upgraded to  20.04
I think there are too many bugs in this version. So what i did was, i backup all the files and did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 19.10.
Still im not planning to upgrade to Ubuntu LTS  unless they resolve the bugs